# Should I validate hidden fields?

Tags: validation

Can a malicious user modify the information submitted through the hidden fields? And if yes, does that mean that it is a good practice to validate and purify the information submitted via hidden fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a malicious user modify the information submitted through the hidden fields?

Yes. It's trivial to do this with a browser's dev tools (like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox, [Chrome Dev Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/), etc.), to say nothing of constructing/manipulating raw HTTP requests.

> And if yes, does that mean that it is a good practice to validate and purify the information submitted via hidden fields?

***Absolutely.***